# Can I use Google oauth2 id_token to access Google services

Tags: android, google-oauth

I implemented this: http://android-developers.blogspot.fi/2013/01/verifying-back-end-calls-from-android.html and then wanted to make the app ask the full name of the user from google servers.

I can get the id_token all right, pass it to the backend, verify it and get the user id and email from the token, but I don't seem to be able to find any way to turn the id_token to a token I could use to authenticate on google servers and request personal info from the profile scope. The google apps-app has the permissions to use the scopes, so as soon as I can understand how to get an auth-token, asking the info shouldn't be a problem.

Is it at all possible to access the google servers with this token, or must I ask for a separate auth token for the personal info.

Comment: Can you share how you were able to "verify it and get the user id and email from the token?" Is there an article that describes these steps or did you know by osmosis? If by osmosis, will you describe what we can do on php server (assuming we pass the token through Authorization Bearer header info or by http post parameter) to get the user_id from an id_token? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should ask for a separate auth token for the personal info.  The user has to explicitly grant permission for your app to see things like their name, gender, etc.

Comment: Thanks, just the info I needed, but didn't want to hear. =P